# want to set y-axis label values in line chart

Tags: python, charts, line, yaxis

[image: line chart]

want to display  the yaxis label in the range 0.2 to 0.8 in the range of 0.2.

example: 0.2,   0.4,   0.6,   0.8

code:

```
plt.axis=([0,0.45,0.2,0.8])
plt.plot([0.2,0.25,0.3,0.35,0.4,0.45],[0.5,0.6,0.60,0.5,0.5,0.6])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be setted with yticks and np.arrange as follows:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

plt.plot([0.2,0.25,0.3,0.35,0.4,0.45],[0.5,0.6,0.60,0.5,0.5,0.6])
plt.yticks(np.arange(0.2, 0.8, step=0.2))
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]
Here is the documentation for [yticks](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.yticks.html)

Hope it helps!